# launch a PyQT window from a main PyQt window, and get the user input?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a main PyQt window, from which I need to get a string of User Input when they hit a certain button.

Here is my code for the User Input window:

```
 class InputDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
   '''
   this is for when you need to get some user input text
   '''
   def __init__(self, parent=None, title='user input', label='comment', text=''):

       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

       #--Layout Stuff---------------------------#
       mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

       layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
       self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
       self.label.setText(label)
       layout.addWidget(self.label)

       self.text = QtGui.QLineEdit(text)
       layout.addWidget(self.text)

       mainLayout.addLayout(layout)

       #--The Button------------------------------#
       layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
       button = QtGui.QPushButton("okay") #string or icon
       self.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.close)
       layout.addWidget(button)

       mainLayout.addLayout(layout)
       self.setLayout(mainLayout)

       self.resize(400, 60)
       self.setWindowTitle(title)
```

From the main window, I am saying:

```
inputter = InputDialog(mainWindowUI, title="comments", label="comments", text="")
inputter.show()
comment = inputter.text.text()
print comment
```

This prints an empty string, even if the user types a comment and hits "OK". Obviously because the main window script does not wait on the `InputDialog` to close. So, how do I get it to wait, so that I may retrieve the user input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
inputter.exec_()
```

instead of

```
inputter.show()
```

From: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html#exec

> This method is also a Qt slot with the C++ signature int exec().
>
> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it.
>   The function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with any
>   other window in the same application until they close the dialog. If
>   the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window is
>   blocked while the dialog is open. By default, the dialog is
>   application modal.
>
> See also open(), show(), result(), and setWindowModality().

Answer (score 3):

I know that utdemir's response solved your problem but I just wanted to say that Qt comes with several convenience input dialogs included. Have a look at [QInputDialog.getText](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qinputdialog.html#getText) for instance.

Comment: QInputDialog.getText link does not work. Maybe this one http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qinputdialog.html#getText can help.