# PyQT: When relaunching plugin I don't get the main window I get the pop up window

Tags: python, pyqt, popup, pyqt4, qgis

I am developing a python plugin on **QGIS** using **PyQT**. My plugin contains a main window and a pop-up window which will be launched when clicking on a button on the main window.

My problem is when I relaunch again the plugin, the pop-up window will be displayed instead of the main window.

I found this on Stack Overflow ([launch a PyQT window from a main PyQt window, and get the user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046882/launch-a-pyqt-window-from-a-main-pyqt-window-and-get-the-user-input)) but it doesn't help me to solve my problem.

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** add code 
In my main window, I call to launch my pop-up window :

```
def show(self):

       self.project.load()

       if self.project.tranus_project:
           self.tranus_folder.setText(self.project.tranus_project.path)

       self.activate_launch_button()
       self.launch_options_TRANUS()
       super(OptionsTRANUSDialog, self).show()   

   ......
   def launch_options_TRANUS(self):

       self.get_checked_list()

       if self.checked_list != [] :

           dialog = launch_tranus_dialog.LaunchTRANUSDialog(self.checked_list,self.folder,self.tranus_binaries,parent=self)
           dialog.show()
           result = dialog.exec_()

       self.reinitialise_checked_list()
```

The class of my pop-up window is defined as :

```
class LaunchTRANUSDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):

    def __init__(self,checked_list,project_directory,tranus_bin_path,parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(LaunchTRANUSDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.project = parent.project
        self.proj = QgsProject.instance()

        self.tranus_bin_path = tranus_bin_path
        self.project_directory = project_directory
        self.project = parent.project
        self.checked_list = checked_list
        self.is_all_checked = False

        self.tabs = self.findChild(QtGui.QTabWidget, 'tabWidget')

        self.proj = QgsProject.instance()
        #control actions
        self.tabs.blockSignals(True) 
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.onChange) 
        self.tabs.blockSignals(False) 

 def show(self):
        self.put_tabs()
        super(LaunchTRANUSDialog, self).show()
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Hello, I have solved my problem, in my main window in method show() I delete  self.activate_launch_button()
           self.launch_options_TRANUS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, in my main window in method show() I delete self.activate_launch_button() 
self.launch_options_TRANUS()